# Order of processing when using Flyway Java based migrations

Tags: flyway

I have just started to experiment with Java based migrations combined with providing a checksum by implementing MigrationChecksumProvider.

Currently Flyway seems to handle things as a 2 step process

- Call the Checksum routine
- Call the JdbcMigration routine

This 2 step approach works well if the JdbcMigration routine is static in nature (such as a script) as the checksum can be easily calculated. It get more interesting if the JdbcMigration routine is dynamic in nature as its result is not known at the time that the checksum routine is called.

The current solution for this is to have the checksum routine also call some form of pre JdbcMigration routine that generates the dynamic DDL to be checksummed and so allowing checksum to be calculated and returned. Flyway can then move onto calling the JdbcMigration routine which then executes the DDL.

The above works, but would it not be better in the future for Flyway to handle this as a 3 step process that it can correctly track and report on.

- Call the preparation routine
- Call the Checksum routine
- Call the JdbcMigration routine

This question/comment/idea has come about because I am currently looking at using JOOQ as a way to express the DDL, which means that the DDL only exists at run time.

Follow up 1

As the checksum needs to be calculated based on the underlying database there is a need for the connection to be passed to the checksum routine as well as the migrate routine. The reason for this is that JOOQ may create different DDL statements depending on what the database target is.

Follow up 2

It would be useful if the ConfigurationAware interface could provide 'discovered' information about the java migration it is calling, such as the version and description it has decoded from the class name.